# Solution Verification: Geometric probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification

*Suppose that there is a loop in a computer program and that the test to exit
the loop depends on the value of a random variable X. The program exits the loop
whenever X ∈ A, and this occurs with probability 1/3. If the loop is executed at least
once, what is the probability that the loop is executed five times before exiting?*

My Solution:

Let  $Y =$ r.v. denoting the number of loops before the program exits. (I am using the geometric distribution to count # of failures before success). Since the probability of the program terminating is $\frac{1}{3}$, we have that: $$Y \sim \text{Geometric}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$$
Hence, $$P(Y = 5 | Y \geq 1) = \frac{P(Y = 5 \cap Y \geq  1)}{P(Y \geq 1)} = \frac{P(Y = 5)}{1 - P(Y < 1)} = \frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{5}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{1 - \frac{1}{3}} = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{4}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$$

Is this the correct approach? Any feedback on my solution would be greatly appreciated.